# MeteorJS -how to combine Add & Edit template

Tags: javascript, meteor, code-organization

I'm trying to figure out how to create a standard CRUD app with one view for Create and Edit.  Currently I have:

```
Flight_add.html
Flight_add.js
Flight_edit.html
Flight_edit.js
```

https://github.com/u843867/pilotlog5/tree/master/client/templates/flights

I'd like to combine into a Flight.html so that the create and edit use the same Template.  Just not sure the best approach.  By the way, I'm using iron:router
Thanks.

Comment: How do you suppose anyone can give any advice how to structure your code when you don't show your code?

Comment: my question is quite generic. i.e. if you have a template to Add 100 fields and one to be able to Edit all those fields how would you implement that.  I haven't finished the EDIT template yet, I'm just looking for some pointers about how others would attack this.

Comment: Sorry, your question is way too broad to be answered. Without proper code samples and a distinct question about those samples you will likely get no useful answers. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And this is where Stack Overflow breaks down. I've had questions like Justin's before where I'm looking for some best practices (I've gone off and designed things on my own before only to realize much later that I should have organized my code or methods differently, and had wished someone with more experience could have guided me in the design beforehand). But SO doesn't allow these questions and people here enforce the rules without giving any useful alternatives for where the asker can go to get such questions answered.

Comment: @Justin, I do agree with others that this is very broad and any answers will be opinionated. One option you can do is mimic how a very organized framework does it (and one which other devs will already be familiar with), such as Ruby on Rails. You can also mimic how the Discover Meteor Book structures its app, which IMO is pretty clear and straightforward. At the end of the day, use what is clear to you and what you figure should be clear to any future devs that may take over or help you with the project.

Comment: thanks for the advice.  Yes, I have looked at Discover Meteor but the Add Post and Edit Post in the Microscope example are 2 separate but almost the same Templates and js helpers.

Answer (score 1):

Create the folder:

```
client/views/flight
```

Then stick flightAdd.html, flightAdd.js, flightEdit.html and flight.js to this folder.

Another option is:

```
client/views/flightAdd with flightAdd.html, flightAdd.js in the folder

client/views/flightEdit with flightEdit.html, flightEdit.js in the folder
```

But there's no right and wrong answer on how to structure your app. Take a look at this example for some guidance on how to structure your app: https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope

Comment: this is pretty much where I'm at right now.  My thoughts were t have a Flight view and for the edit function when I call it I want to send the Flight I selected to edit and in the Add I will just render the view and not send any Flight.  I'm just wanting to a) know if this is feasible (I'm not very experienced) and b) An example would be useful.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're saying. I'd say have a look at the aldeed packages (collection2, simple schema, autoform) and specifically the autoform package which makes it very easy to create insert and edit forms. There are examples in the docs